# How to construct object path dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JSON object and I am iterating through it. I am using different values from different levels of it.

But I am not able to create path dynamically to reiterate the object.

```
var data= {
  "algoName": "textClassification",
  "hyperParams": {
    "mode": {
      "data_type": "string",
      "default_value": "supervised",
      "required": true,
      "description": "The training mode",
      "allowedValues": [
        "supervised",
        "unsupervised"
      ]
    }
  }
}

var key1;
for(var key in data.hyperParams) {

  key1=key;

}
var text1 =  "data.hyperParams" + key1

for(var key in text1) {
  console.log(text1[key]);
}
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I am trying to iterate through object but "for(var key in text1)" is not working properly it is taking text1 as sting not a path. So instead of giving values it is giving letters that makes the text1 string.

Comment: I can read your question at least two ways. I'm fairly sure you want to use a string path to access a nested value; that's what [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) does. But if you just want to access a non-nested property by string name instead, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you T.J. Crowder. I modified code as following and it is working now.

```
for(var key in data.hyperParams[key1]) {
  console.log(data.hyperParams[key1][key]);
}
```